# PIC32 bluetooth

Tags: microcontroller, pic, bluetooth, embedded

I want to implement bluetooth communication on my final bachelor project, but I'm having a lot of doubts.

One of the requisites of this project is to have a Java application that can talk to the micro via Bluetooth. After a lot of research, I've found one that I think it's very good with a SPP profile, but I still have a lot of questions about it:

1. All the bluetooth on a PC implements the SPP profile stack?
2. If you need to develop a Java application that runs on every PC that implements the SPP stack, how would you do it?
3. We started by trying to use BlueCove and JavaBluetooth.org API, the first one runs great but I don't know if it's just on my PC and the second one sends an error (Stack not initialized). Which one would you use, and why?
4. We decided to buy this [bluetooth module, from Sparkfun](http://www.sparkfun.com/products/10269), any comments for those of you who already use it?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I used a similar product for my senior design project from Sparkfun (RN-41): http://www.sparkfun.com/products/10559

It worked right out of the box as a simple UART. This allowed my team and I to develop a simple C# application that used the .NET SerialPort class (System.IO.Ports) to communicate between an MSP430 and the PC application we were developing. If streaming data is all you care about, these Bluetooth modules work great. Java implements a similar SerialPort class for RS-232 communications. Don't forget that Bluetooth was developed to replace a serial cable.

I hope this answer helps! Good luck.

Comment: I concur.  I've used RN-41 in a commercial prototype with success.

Answer (score 1):

I personnally achieved to use the Sparkfun's bluesmirf devices to communicate with my own Java application (an Eclipse plug-in). I tested it successfully under Windows, MacOS & Linux based systems.
I used the [RXTX Java library](http://rxtx.qbang.org) to connect to the corresponding serial port once the Bluetooth devices were paired. Under Linux I even achieved to configure rfcomm to automatically pair the Bluetooth devices on demand.

From my experiment I encountered some stability issues... Sometimes it simply fails to connect to the given port even if it exists or refuse to reconnect on it. Sometimes it hangs the whole system...
I never found any good solution to fix those issues that seems to be completely system dependent. I would be interested if any one achieved to use it properly...